# Windows 2008 R2 - Restrict installation of "DHCP Server Role"

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, dhcp

I've got a bunch of machines running in a sensitive network environment. I'm worried that one of the users might install the DHCP Server Role on one of the machines in the network and hose the environment.

Anybody know how to restrict the installation of this server role? 
I'm thinking Windows Group Policy or something along those lines?

Comment: The user has admin privilege to do this?

Comment: windows does have other mechanisms to protect against rogue dhcp services but they are not perfect.  I'd threaten the users with there lifes if they stupidly installed a dhcp server.  But wtf would they have admin and still be stupid enough to install a dhcp server.

Comment: Do you not have any smart switches/routers that can detect rogue DHCP servers?  If users are going to have admin rights, perhaps they should be in their own VLAN?

Comment: 1.Why do users have access to servers at a level that allows them to add roles? 2. What type of hosing do you think would occur?

Comment: @joeqwerty- developers suck and take shortcuts, or the company they work for is too cheap to update the code from 1982 too make it not require admin rights on the server to run.

Answer (score 0):

IN a windows active directory domain you have to authorize a dhcp servre before it will start providing service. If you set up a standalone machine on a subnet with an authorized server, the standalone server will not provide service.  See [Authorizing DHCP servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781697%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) for details on how servers are detected.

Comment: only wish this was bullet proof its not by any means.

Comment: what have you seen to bypass this?  I don't see how it's any less bulletproof than on the router.

Comment: if he has a sensitive enviro then he should be more worried about non windows based dhcp servers and switchport protected will prevent any rogue dhcp server from servicing clients.

Comment: Right but the solution to that is to turn on domain and server isolation, so that no rogue computers can communicate with any asset.  thats that's basic windows security mechanism that should be in place regardless of DHCP role concerns.

Comment: yes all true but something seems wierd about this question and I can't quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score -4):

If your users only have user privileges they won't be able to install any role. Having said that. You should really block this in your network switches.

Comment: This isn't a good answer. 1. An Administrator is a user, so what type of user priveleges are you referring to? If you meant standard user then you should be specific and state that. 2. Block it in the switches? Pray tell how that would be accomplished. Give some detail in your answer .

Comment: This site is not for complete newbs so i think we all understand what rutgers was saying.  And if your on a switched network you can enable switchport protected on all switch ports, then create an acl to prevent other dhcp servers from coming online.

Comment: tony: I agree, but on the other hand, we shouldn't have to intepret what someone means in their answer, especially if the OP isn't experienced enough to "read between the lines".